# LoadLibray FileNotFound depending on which application calls

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to impletement a C++ dll named (let's say) name.dll, which loads another dll (not mine) that is also named name.dll.

In my name.dll implementation I'm loading the real name.dll using this line :

```
            driver_library = LoadLibrary(_T("c:\\windows\\system32\\name.dll"));
```

My dll is in a program.exe.local folder so that the program load mine before the real one in System32.

Depending on which program.exe uses my dll, LoadLibrary **either works fine or returns my own name.dll handle** as driver_library, with GetLastError() returning "file not found".

In https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx it is explicit stated that "If the string specifies a full path, the function searches only that path for the module." Why and how does it load itself for some applications ?

What in the program.exe application could affect LoadLibrary's behavior ?

@Franck Boyne commented : 
"You have two programs - let's call them fine.exe and own.exe. The fine.exe program loads your own name.dll and then loads the other name.dll from System32. The own.exe program loads your own name.dll but when it calls LoadLibrary you get back another handle to your own name.dll instead of a handle to the one from System32."

About own.exe (which is not at all my "own" application) : 
-> name.dll is located in an own.exe.local folder I created, which is located in own.exe directory.

-> own.exe had an application.manifest file that I deleted (the application still launches correctled without it if not using my dll). own.exe does not have an embedded manifest (checked using sigcheck).

-> name.dll is not one of Windows "known dlls" from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs

-> own.exe does not load name.dll using LoadLibrary() (checked by setting a breakpoint into LoadLibrary/A/W/Ex functions)

-> own.exe and name.dll are both 64 bits.

About fine.exe (it's a sample, I have access to the code):

-> name.dll is located in the fine.exe application directory.

-> No manifest file (either embedded or text).

Comment: This doesn't sound like anything more than broken error checking.  If LoadLibrary() returns a non-NULL handle then you must *not* call GetLastError().  If you do anyway then you'll get a random number, it is only 0 by accident.

Comment: Maybe you're right and it's zero by accident, however the handle it returns for sure is the handle to my own name.dll and this does not seem random at all

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible your problem program is using DLL Redirection?

From the LoadLibrary documentation (emphasis added) ...

> If a path is specified and there is a redirection file for the application, the function searches for the module in the application's directory. **If the module exists in the application's directory, LoadLibrary ignores the specified path and loads the module from the application's directory**. If the module does not exist in the application's directory, LoadLibrary loads the module from the specified directory. For more information, see [Dynamic Link Library Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

**Update 6/4/2018**

Here's what I think is happening.

Both of your programs are using [load-time dynamic linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (sometimes called [implicit linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll#determining-which-linking-method-to-use)) to link to a DLL called `name.dll`.  I'm assuming both programs just specify `name.dll` without a full path name.  If you want to check I think you can run [`dumpbin /imports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/imports-dumpbin) against `fine.exe` and `own.exe` to examine the DLL name.

### fine.exe

In the case of the program that does what you expect (loads the second `name.dll` from \Windows\System32) there's no DLL redirection involved so the [standard DLL Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) is followed during the implicit link.  The application directory is searched before the system directory so your copy of `name.dll` gets loaded.

Then your `name.dll` executes a `LoadLibrary` call specifying a full path to the file `C:\Windows\System32\name.dll`.  Since there's no redirection going on, the system directory version of `name.dll` gets loaded as you expect.

### own.exe

In the case of the program that doesn't do what you expect (gets a handle to your own version of `name.dll` twice) there is DLL redirection going on because you have a directory called `own.exe.local` in the application folder.  Since there's redirection going on, during the implicit link the standard search order is ignored and `name.dll` is loaded from `own.exe.local`.

Then your `name.dll` executes a `loadlibrary` call specifying a full path to the file `C:\Windows\System32\name.dll`.  **But** this time there is redirection going on.  The full path specified in the `LoadLibrary` call is ignored and the module is loaded from the redirection folder `own.exe.local`.

Since that copy of `name.dll` has already been loaded by the implicit linking you just get another handle to the module.

As was pointed out in the comments, the `GetLastError` result is misleading.  The `LoadLibrary` call didn't return NULL (it returned a handle to your own `name.dll`) so the value returned by `GetLastError` doesn't apply to the `LoadLibrary` call.

Comment: Thank's for pointing that out. 
There is no redirection file, however there is a folder application.exe.local inside which my name.dll is located. I created this folder and deleted the application.manifest file so that application.exe is tricked into taking my dll instead of the real Windows/System32/name.dll. 
(Simply storing my name.dll in the application directory does not work (application.exe uses the System32/name.dll, probably because it's loaded with an absolute path in the app from what you've told me)).

Any idea how I could get around this issue ?

Comment: Quick clarification : if I create a redirection file application.exe.local, store my name.dll and this redirection file alongside application.exe, the app still does not load my dll. Only the application.exe.local/name.dll folder thing seems to work.

Comment: An application manifest introduces (or removes?) another wrinkle.  The [Dynamic Link Library Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600(v=vs.85).aspx) article says **If the application has a manifest, then any .local files are ignored.**.  But my brain isn't working at the moment, I'll have to think about this tomorrow. :-)

Comment: I've edited my question with what I've checked so far, thanks for your help :)

Comment: You have two programs - let's call them `fine.exe` and `own.exe`.  The `fine.exe` program loads your own `name.dll` and then loads the other `name.dll` from `System32`.  The `own.exe` program loads your own `name.dll` but when it calls `LoadLibrary` you get back another handle to your own `name.dll` instead of a handle to the one from `System32`.  Please could you edit your question to show whether each of these programs has a manifest - embedded or external - and where your own `name.dll` is located for each program?